# Removing images and assets from appcompact-v7 android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I updated my adt some time back and now for every project appcompact-v7 is added automatically. My current project relies on appcompact library but I am having problems of size. My standalone app's apk file is about 12 mb in memory. After unzipping my apk I found that the drawable-xxxx folder of appcompact v7 content is included in my app too but I have not used any of those images in my code. Mostly I am importing support packages and themes. I tried android lint and AndroidUnusedResources.jar. They only provide list of the resources that i am not using. I tried to delete the images from the drawable folder of appcompact but it started throwing all kinds or errors. Is there a quick way to fix it. I looked at other SO post but couldnot find a suitable answer.

Comment: 12mb isn't that much, if someone doesn't know of an automated process is there a restriction on the size that would require the headache of manually breaking down the library? It can just get to be rough depending on how much you are trying to clear from your library if you aren't sure how everything is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this tool but I heard it can point out unused resources in your project. Why don't you give it a try!

https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/

EDIT:
Now that you know unused resources, you can start deleting them. If the error occurs, see the list of errors in **Problems** tab and delete the line that is creating the error. It takes time but it works! I am completely unaware of tools that can automate this process though.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I have tried that library and I got the unused resources in my project. But it was unable to show unused images from appcompactv7. Also images from appcompactv7 that i have not used are added in my apk file and I want to remove those images. This library only gives the list of unused resources that I inculded in src.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble but the issue was not in appcompact. I had used 15 png's for background and they were really large.